# Use awk to interpret }{ as RS and output with ORS }\n{

Tags: awk

I have data that looks like this:

```
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

It's as if you took a newline-delimited json file and removed all the newlines.

I'm trying to use awk to convert it to to ndjson.

That is, my expected output is this:

```
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

I don't want to load the entire file into memory *(which is why I'm not using sed)*, so my thought is I should use `}{` as row separator.   Then, I figure if I use `}\n{` as ORS I should get my desired output.

So I tried this:

```
cat my-file.txt | awk -v RS="}{" -v ORS="}\n{" '{$1=$1}1'
```

But it doesn't work!

Here's the output I get:

```
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}
{}
{{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}
{}
{}
{
```

Apart from the constraint of not loading the entire file into memory, I don't care what bash command is used, but my thinking is awk will be the way.  E.g. if `tr` supported multi-character expressions, that would be fine with me.

Please help me understand why this isn't working as expected and what I need to change.

Thanks!

**Update**

Following the answers given, will add some learnings.

The TLDR is don't use a macOS if you need to do trickier things like this.

For one this doen't work on mac: `echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n" | head -n -2`; it complains about illegal line parameter, but this is valid on a linux system.

The other problem was the way awk was working on my (mac) system.

My awk command was close to correct.

On linux it produces this output:

```
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}}
{
```

So I just have to find a way to trim the trailing `}\n{` *(and as pointed out in the answer, the `{$1=$1}` is not necessary)*.

But all of those extraneous newlines were due to the screwy implementation of awk on my system ( It wasn't gawk and i'm not sure what it was ).

Comment: Use '{"anonymousId"' as the record separator.

Comment: tried your suggestion @RamanSailopal but it does not work

Comment: Do you  mean JSON-like? What you haven't isn't JSON (objects as bare values without a corresponding key), but if it is JSON, you shouldn't be using `awk` at all.

Comment: @anubhava while it won't fail in the way the OP is seeing, that won't work as-is because it doesn't account for the ORS that will be printed at the end of the file. The `$1=$1` also isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: I understand your data is all on 1 line but does that 1 line have a terminating newline (i.e. is it a valid text file per POSIX) or not?

Comment: @EdMorton no terminating newline in the file

Comment: Hmm, that makes your input not a valid text file per POSIX so while gawk can handle it YMMV with what any other text processing tool does with it. You might want to fix whatever is producing that file so it's output is a valid text file (i.e. has a terminating newline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `$1=$1` inside `awk -v RS='}{' -v ORS='}\n{' '{$1=$1}1' file` isn't useful - it tells awk to recompile the current record replacing all chains of white space with blanks but you the only white space in your example is the `\n` at the end of the file and there's no point converting that to a blank. So your script can be reduced to:

```
awk -v RS='}{' -v ORS='}\n{' '1' file
```

but `RS='}{'` means different things to different awk variants.

Use of a multi-char RS with GNU awk (and probably a couple of others now) means that the RS is treated as a regexp to separate the records:

```
$ awk -v RS='}{' -v ORS='}\n{' '1' file
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
}
{$
```

Note the extra `}\n{` added at the end because there is no `}{` at the end of your input and so the end of input itself indicates the end of a record and so gets replaced with the ORS value.

Use of a multi-char RS with a POSIX awk means that the 2nd and subsequent chars in the RS get ignored and the first char is taken as the RS, hence the output you reported seeing in your question:

```
$ awk --posix -v RS='}{' -v ORS='}\n{' '1' file
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}
{}
{{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}
{}
{
}
{$
```

where **every** `}` alone gets treated as matching RS and so gets replaced by ORS.

So you are not using an awk that supports multi-char RS. Your choices are to install one (preferably gawk) and do:

```
$ awk -v RS='}[{\n]' '{ORS=gensub(/}{/,"}\n{",1,RT)} 1' file
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

otherwise do something like this with any awk:

```
$ awk --posix -v RS='{' -v ORS= '{print pfx $0; pfx=(/}$/ ? "\n" : "") RS}' file
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

In the gawk solution above we define the RS as `'}[{\n]'` to say that the records mid-line are terminated by `}{` but the record at the end of the line is terminated by `}\n`. So RT holds `}{` for every record except the last one on the line which is `}\n` if your line ends with `\n` or NULL otherwise and so we just have to set ORS to be RT but with `}{` converted to `}\n{` for those records where RT has that value, otherwise ORS just gets set to `}\n` when RT has that value or NULL if your input didn't have a terminating `\n`.

An alternative gawk solution that I think I might actually prefer would be:

```
$ awk -v RS='}{' -v ORS='}\n{' 'NR>1{print prev} {prev=$0} END{printf "%s",prev}' file
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

---

**EDIT:** original answer for posterity before I noticed the OP said they don't want to read the whole file into memory:

Simple substitutions on individual strings like this is what sed is best at:

```
$ sed 's/}{/}\n{/g' file
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

otherwise with any awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/}{/,"}\n{")} 1' file
{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

Comment: Could you explain the gawk solution a little more? e.g. the brackets in `RS` and how the actual awk command is working?  Also what would be more performant / better -- your expression, or removing gensub and running truncate on the result i.e. `awk -v RS="}{" -v ORS="}\n{" '1' file.txt > out.txt; truncate -s-3 out.txt`

Comment: OK I added an explanation. As for that pipe to truncate - idk if that'd be faster or not but adding chars and then removing them is always a less attractive solution than just not adding them in the first place and there are other ways to do it within awk if the gensub() approach was too slow or otherwise unattractive - I just added one to my answer where it always prints the previous line and so can handle printing the last line by not adding ORS.

Answer (score 0):

using record separator will create an extra delimiter at the end of the file, since it's static we can just remove it afterwards

```
$ echo '{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}' | 
  awk -v RS='}{' -v ORS='}\n{' 1 | head -n -2


{"anonymousId":"abc123",{"hello":"world"}}
{"anonymousId":"abc456",{"hi": "again"}}
```

if you don't have `gawk` for multi-char RS support, you can have this workaround

```
$ echo ... | 
  awk -v RS='}' 'NF{printf "%s", $0 RS} !NF{print RS}' | head -n -2
```

there will be an extra RS, which will be trimmed afterwards.

Comment: why do you add `head  -n2`?  what if your file has more than 2 lines?  I only kept it to 2 records for brevity here.

Comment: @dstandish it is a typo, supposed to be `head -n -2` to count from the end of file. It will filter out the last two lines which are the extra RS printed.

Comment: ok -- i think this removes too much.  we need to remove `}\n{` which is only one newline and one trailing `}`

Comment: Perhaps... anyway you can test to verify.

Comment: of course and i did, i just say _i think_ cus i could have done something wrong.  anyway thanks for the answer